# Solving system of linear equations ( 4 variables, 3 equations)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Finding the solution(s) for:

$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
2x_1+x_2+3x_3+2x_4 &=5\\
 x_1+x_2+x_3+2x_4&=3\\
-x_2+x_3+6x_4&=3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

I tried using elimination to rewrite the system in row echelon form, then back substituting. I have no idea what I did wrong, or if I was doing the elimination process correctly.. but I kept getting stuck. I am confused and not really sure how to proceed, I must be awful because I've been staring at this problem for hours.

Comment: pudge  Why did you delete your first post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122976/solving-a-system-of-linear-equaions-4-variables-3-equations, after this post here was identified as a duplicate of it?  That's game-playing. And therefore I have flagged this question, and your behavior.

Comment: I deleted it because it was a duplicate though? It was an issue so I got rid of it. On my first question it was reformatted and it appeared that the question I had was with the wrong equations I wanted. I was confused -> new correct post -> delete the older one. jeez

Comment: Well, you've got a duplicate to turn to and apply to this system of 4 variables and three equations.  And, regardless, when you've posted a question, and want to edit it, you are to **edit it**, not leave it and ask the same question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the third row to the first one and adding the third one to the second one you obtain
\begin{array}{lcl}
2x_1+4x_3+8x_4&=&8\\
x_1+2x_3+8x_4&=&6\\
-x_2+x_3+6x_4&=&3
\end{array}
Now multiply the second equation by $2$ and subtract it from the first one
\begin{array}{lcl}
-8x_4&=&-4\\
x_1+2x_3+8x_4&=&6\\
-x_2+x_3+6x_4&=&3
\end{array}
Now you know that $x_4=2$ and hence
\begin{array}{lcl}
x_4&=&2\\
x_1+2x_3&=&-10\\
x_3&=&-9+x_2
\end{array}
Finally subtract the last one multiplied by two from the second equation
\begin{array}{lcl}
x_4&=&2\\
x_1&=&8-2x_2\\
x_3&=&-9+x_2
\end{array}
Now it's clear that your system has an infinite number of solutions (one per each value given to $x_2$). This is not surprising since you have four variables and just three equations.

Comment: x4 = 1/2 not 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can call $x_1=p$ and get the system:

$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x_2+3x_3+2x_4 &=5-2p\\
x_2+x_3+2x_4&=3-p\\
-x_2+x_3+6x_4&=3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

If you sum the last equation at the first and second you get

$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
4x_3+8x_4 &=8-2p\\
2x_3+8x_4&=6-p\\
-x_2+x_3+6x_4&=3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

Now subtract the second at the first

$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
2x_3 &=2-p\\
2x_3+8x_4&=6-p\\
-x_2+x_3+6x_4&=3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

And solve as usual. Your solution will be a function of $p$.

Can you finish?

Comment: When you call x1 = p, x1 would be considered a free variable, correct?

Comment: @pudge: yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{matrix}
2& 1 &3 &2 &|&5\\
1 &1 &1 &2 &|&3\\
0 &-1& 1& -2&|&-1\\
0&-1& 1& 6& |&3\\
0& 0& 0& -8& |&-4\end{matrix}\\
x_4 = \frac 12\\
-x_2+x_3 =0\\
x_2 = x_3 = t\\
x_1 + 2t + 1 = 3\\
x_1 = 2-2t\\$

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (2,0,0,\frac 12) + (-2,1,1,0)t$

Comment: Sorry, new to the subject and this made no sense to me!

Comment: There is a line of solutions (not a single solution).  What I have there is the  vector representation of that line.

Comment: As for the top section, I have put the equation in to augmented matrix form, and then conducted row operations to reduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up learning this in the next section, so I understand now.